# Opening a new terminal and working on the opened terminal through a python script

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I am trying to open a terminal using gnome-terminal command in a python script. How do I run the subsequent commands of the script on the opened terminal and not on the parent terminal?

Comment: Why would you want to do this. But you can always use the -e parameter

Comment: Actually I am running a test suite ,prior to which I have to source the framework, go to the repository and pull the latest scripts and copy them to my local directory.I am trying to write a script for the above procedure. I am running the suites on three different platforms, which requires three terminals if they are to be run simultaneously. @Natecat

Comment: Or run 3 instances of the script

Comment: yup..i will try doing that..Actually there was some issue with the vi editor..it was having some extra characters which was causing a failure. after using a dos2unix command it started working fine. thank you for your help @Natecat